# PHP-Date returns wrong and static minute

Tags: php, date

I already restarted Apache, but on executing `echo date("d-M-Y H:m:00");`, it return every time something like that:

> 11-Aug-2016 00:08:00

I don't know exactly why it has every time `08` for minute-value and that's obviously wrong. As you can see in the code, I'm only defining seconds.
The server has the correct time, executing the command line `date` returns something like that:

> Thu Aug 11 00:06:53 CEST 2016

Comment: `m` is months (as a number with leading 0), `i` is minutes in the date mask - [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker OMG, sorry, how embarrassing ... I forgot that, but thank you! I searched for ages for the error.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php